# Active record query to get parents with first child that falls within a date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need an active record query that counts the number of Parents with their FIRST Child within a date range.

For example

```
<%= Parent.joins(:children).where("children.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", 2019-01-01, 2020-01-01).uniq.count %>
```

Would return the count of the Parents with ANY children created within the date range.

However, I only want to get the Parents if their FIRST Child was created within the date range.

How do I get the count of Parents with FIRST Child created between two dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with 2 queries,

First get all children ids for first-child only records(assuming children.id is incremental unsigned integers, otherwise will have to apply ORDER BY with created_at DESC),

```
first_child_ids = Parent.joins(:children).group('parents.id').select('MIN(children.id)')
```

Then get the count,

```
count = Parent.joins(:children).where('children.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', start, end).where(children: {id: first_child_ids}).count
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I have a similar question that you might be able to help with. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/q/58308005/3154739