# Active Record query to find parents with child within a date range and child prior to that date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need an active record query that returns the count of Parents with a Child created within a date range AND a Child created prior to the date range.

I currently have the following two queries:
This query returns the count of Parents with a Child created within the date range

```
Parent.joins(:children).where("children.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", start, end).distinct.count(parent_id)
```

This query counts the Parents with a Child created before the date range

```
Parent.joins(:children).where("children.created_at < ?", start).distinct.count(:parent_id)
```

I need to find the count of Parents that have a Child created within the range AND a Child created before the range.

How is the best way to get this result?

Comment: Are `Parent` and `Child` different models?

Comment: Yes Parent and Child are different models

Comment: check out my answer to fetch the desired result in a single query.

Comment: Your answer doesn't work for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in following ways,

Simple way, get the ids for parent from the first query and apply the filter on parent id in second query,

```
 q1_pids = Parent.joins(:children)
                 .where("children.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", start, end)
                 .ids
 count = Parent.joins(:children)
               .where("children.created_at < ?", start)
               .where(id: q1_pids)
               .count("parents.id")
```

Using INTERSECT

```
q1 = Parent.joins(:children)
           .where("children.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", start, end)

q2 = Parent.joins(:children)
           .where("children.created_at < ?", start)

count = (q1 & q1).count
```

Second solution just uses [array intersection](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-26), however you can prepare the SQL statement yourself to fire a single SQL query to the database.

Comment: @Sujan how is your first solution different from my answer? Am i missing something?

Comment: @AkshayGoyal, same reason. A single children record can't have both created_at being in range (start, end) and created_at < start. Since the first condition contradicts the second

Comment: Since this is a one-to-many relation, both a the conditions can be met for a parent entry on different occasions. Hence 2 queries are needed.

Comment: Got it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Sujan's answer, you can fetch all the records in a single query as well.

```
Parent.joins(:children)
      .joins('INNER JOIN children AS before_start_children ON before_start_children.parent_id = parents.id')
      .where(children: {created_at: start..end})
      .where("before_start_children.created_at < ?", start)
      .distinct
      .count(parent_id)
```

Comment: I thought that it would work, too. But it always returns 0.

Comment: Can you share sample data?

Comment: @AkshayGoyal relation between Parent and Children seems one-to-many, OP wants to get the count of records which match both the condition *but on* different occasions. Hence INTERSECT is the solution here

Comment: Updated my answer.